# Mongodb incr all values in a nest document

Tags: mongodb

Here is my document:

```
{
  "memberAges": {
    "alice": 20,
    "bob": 18,
    "cathy": 25
  }
}
```

`memberAges` may have vary keys.

Now I need to incr all the numbers at once, any ideas?

Comment: do you want to update all documents in that collection or only single one ?

Comment: @mickl Seems like he might want to update all documents in the collection and by the condition that there can be many keys and it can be varied.